# Introducir datos en una tabla de la libreria JsPdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

Buen dia,

estoy trabajando con un pluging llamado jsPdf-autotable de la libreria jsPdf la cual genera un Pdf por medio de javascript, el primer codigo mostraré un ejemplo en el cual imprimo una tabla con informacion de productos, la columna producto al poder contener muchos caracteres, queda ajustada automaticamente, imprime 1 linea pero ese 1 lo puedo establecer contando las filas del array que quiero incluir luego, el cual muestro en el codigo 2

Codigo 1

function generar_pdf()
{
 var producto=manzana;
  function filas(fila)
  {
    fila = fila || 10;
    let body = [];
    for (var j = 1; j

Hasta aqui me genera un pdf con una tabla de encabezado armado arriba y 1 fila con los datos de la funcion filas

codigo 2----------------------

Aqui obtengo como respuesta ajax la variable 'respuesta', es un array que armé consultado en mysql por php los cuales me trae X cantidad de productos, cada uno con su nombre, valor, iva, cantidad etc... se que el 4 de arriba lo debo cambiar por la X cantidades leyendo el legnth del array, la pregunta es, como meto los datos del array en la funcion final para que me imprima el pdf correctamente

//Tomo cuantos datos tiene el array que envié desde PHP
success(respuesta)
{
    var len = respuesta.length;

    for( var i = 0; i

Answer (score 0):

En el codigo que tu agregas no veo la declaracion de los parametros de la tabla para el ancho de columna lo puedes declarar manualmente algo asi como:

```
doc.autoTable(columns, JSON.parse(rows), {
        margin: {horizontal: 5},
        bodyStyles: {valign: 'middle'},
        styles: {overflow: 'linebreak', columnWidth:'wrap'},
        theme: 'plain',
        columnStyles: {
            text: {
                columnWidth: 'wrap'
            },
            Columna1: {
                columnWidth: 45,
                fontStyle: 'bold',
                textColor: 240                
            },

            Columna2: {
                columnWidth: 45
            }

        }
    });
```